# How does set works with unique keys but with equivalent value of keys in C++?

Tags: c++, set, g++

```cpp
vector< pair<int,int> > v; 
    // using indices for comparing pairs
auto func = [&](int i, int j) { return v[i] > v[j]; };
    // set which will store the indices and compare keys using
    // func based on values in v
set<int, decltype(func)> index_set(func);
```

If I have two same values `v[0]={1,2}` and `v[1]={1,2}` and I insert them into the `index_set`, i.e.

```cpp
index_set.insert(0);
index_set.insert(1);
```

**Reality:**
I will have only 1 element in `index_set` (`index_set.size()=1`), which is only index `0` and index `1` is not inserted.

**Expectations:** Both `0` and `1` must be inserted.

**Rationale:**
According to [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/), it says:

```
Unique keys
    No two elements in the container can have equivalent keys.
```

Because keys are not equivalent (`0 != 1`) so set should contain both `0` and `1`. Why is this behaviour justified? I think I am confusing for values of keys for literal values of keys.

**Minimal, Complete, Verfiable example**: [Try this code on ideone!](https://ideone.com/NHQUgJ)

Comment: @Galik, Is the edit helpful?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] so that we can better understand what is going on?

Comment: @jamesdlin @Galik, I think of uniqueness of keys in terms of value of key  (`0` and `1`) as different from value which the keys hold (`v[0]` and `v[1]`). This created confusion, because according to me set will store in its BST  value of `0` and `1` and will compare keys (strictly less) using the comparator, but the values of keys are **also compared** using the same comparator and therefore it caused confusion.

Comment: But your *values* are not simply `0` and `1`. Your *values* have more information *associated* with them by virtue of the *comparator* you provided which links them to that additional information.

Comment: @madhur4127 How *you* think of key uniqueness doesn't change what criteria `std::set` actually uses to determine key uniqueness, and that criteria is specified by the comparison function.  Also, for `std::set`, keys and values are the same.  If you want them to be different, you should be using `std::map`.

Answer (score 1):

[cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) states further down on the page:

> *Compare*
>   ...
>   The `set` object uses this expression to determine both the order the elements follow in the container and whether two element keys are equivalent (by comparing them reflexively: they are equivalent if `!comp(a,b) && !comp(b,a)`). No two elements in a `set` container can be equivalent.

You've specified a custom comparison function that states that elements `0` and `1` should be considered equal.  Therefore your `std::set` will keep only one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The compare function you are using is not very intuitive. The way it's been implemented, `0` and `1` are considered equivalent. If you insert `1` first, `0` will not be inserted.

If you have

```
v[0] = {1, 2};
v[1] = {1, 2};
v[2] = {2, 2};
v[3] = {1, 2}
```

Then, `0`, `1,` and `3` will be considered equivalent as far as the `set` is concerned.